# Fossil evidence of common ancestor to Great Apes and Humans

Tags: biology, evolution

Where can I find documentation of fossil findings about ancient human anscestors, even down to the point of believed divergence between great apes and humans? I heard a skeleton has been found earlier than both species, but with large sensory organs and a more ape-like structure, but can't find anything on it.

Any resources appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In what way is this a history question? In what way is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_evolution insufficient for your needs?